# Relatório de alterações em Banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados, modelo-relacional

Gente tenho varias tabelas que alguns usuários vão ter permissões de alterações. Preciso ter uma tabela de alterações feitas pelo usuário. Vou dar um exemplo.
 Vamos supor uma tabela produtos, esse produto vai está em vários estabelecimentos com preços diferentes isso me gera uma tabela produtos-estabelecimento certo? Agora é que vem minha duvida, o usuário vai alterar o preço e eu preciso armazenar os preços anteriores, quem alterou e qual foi esse estabelecimento. É correto criar uma tabela alteração e criar um relacionamento com produtos-estabelecimento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O correto seria você criar uma tabela de log, com as chaves primárias, chaves estrangeiras, com o preço antigo, novo preço e código do funcionário que alterou o preço. A melhor prática é utilizar uma Trigger que dispara toda vez que alguém insere, atualiza ou exclui um preço.

Comment: Entendi, apenas criar um log com todos as informações que preciso. Só mais uma pergunta, Apenas com Trigger e Log dá para fazer isso? Gosto de ter duas opções sempre. É bom ter um plano B. kkkkk

Comment: Acredito que a melhor solução é fazer dessa maneira, mas você pode fazer de outro jeito sim, você pode criar uma tabela com o histórico do preço de cada produto. Você teria que colocar todas as informações importantes nessa tabela. **Ex:** COD_PRODUTO, PRECO, DATA_INICIO, DATA_FIM, COD_USUARIO (com o usuário que alterou a informação).